# SVG looks ok in browser, but not when included as 'img src=file.svg'

Tags: html, svg

I'm having trouble displaying an svg image correctly on an html page.
I created the image using snapsvg, extracted the svg and added xml and doctype tags.

The svg and the test page code is here:
https://gist.github.com/falconair/ed0fbbc5db4135d0f1b2

When I open the svg in chrome, it looks fine. When I open it in this html, the text at the boddom disappears, replaced by dashes:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
  <img src="/assets/composingcontracts/mappingdiagram.svg" width="850px" height="450px">
  <img src="/assets/composingcontracts/mappingdiagram.svg" width="100%" height="100%">
</body>
</html>
```

Note that I display the image twice, once using 100% height/width and once using explicit values, I get the same result.

What's more, when I include this image in my actual web page (jekyll blog post), no matter what height/width values I use, only the top third of the image shows!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a specific size like `width="850px" height="450px"`, then the whole image should show.  Unless it is in a container (eg. `<div>`) which is smaller than that.

However, when you use percentages (`width="100%" height="100%"`), that is referring to the size of the SVG "viewport", which is normally the parent object.  But if you haven't specified a specific size for that parent element, SVG has to do some guessing.

What happens when you specify (100% x 100%) is that SVG sets the width of the SVG to 100% of the parent container. Then it tries to calculate a height based on that width and the aspect ratio of the SVG - which it gets from the `viewBox`.  If there is no viewBox, it falls back to the default height for indeterminate elements, which is 150px.  That will be why you are only seeing the top third.

You could fix this issue by adding `viewBox="0 0 850 450"` to your SVG.  However then the SVG size will be controlled by its parent container.  Which you will need to at least give a width to, otherwise the SVG will be scaled down to that "indeterminate" height of 150px.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up converting it to png as Macoi suggested, but your answer contains the information I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Try exporting the image using the PNG file format and use the 100% height/weight. Hope it works.

Comment: Thanks, I did just convert it to png. Paul's resolved the issue I brought up in the question, but I shouldn't have wasted a day on the issue in the first place. I should have just converted it :)